# How to map a function to each dictionary element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary `self.what_to_build`
I am iterating on each element, and apply another method to each element using the following way:

```
[self.typeBuild(obj_type,dest) for obj_type,dest in self.what_to_build.items()]
```

It is my understanding this builds a list in memory, while there is no real impact on the program, I would like to refrain from this, I really do not need the list, just applying the method. 
How would I do this same map, in the most Pythonic way, without doing a list comprehension

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a regular loop:

```
for obj_type,dest in self.what_to_build.items():
    self.typeBuild(obj_type, dest)
```

A list comprehension indeed creates a list object with the return values of the `self.typeBuild()` calls, which is a waste of CPU and memory if you don't need those return values.

Don't get too hung up trying to write 'compact' code; readability is found in just the right level of verbosity.

Comment: I accept this, but, out of curiosity, as I am learning the language and I might see this in other people's code. Is there a way of doing it in one line, similar to list compre'

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka: I'd reject any such attempts in code reviews, to be honest. There is no *sensible* way to do this in one line, nor should you try to do it anyway.

Comment: I agree with your approach. But, when learning a new language, is good to see ALL the language can offer, not just the "best practice" part...and thank you for the answer.

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka: The (wrong) list comprehension approach is what you'll mostly see. Perhaps someone trying to be *too clever* could use a `dequeue()` object with a maximum size set to 0 and a generator expression. It's not pretty, not readable and I'm not going to spell it out here either. :-)

Comment: I agree. Since performance is the most common reason to choose one over the other, my advice is to not worry about it and just pick one; if you find that your program is running too slowly, then and only then should you go back and worry about tuning your code.